# How do I cancel password request on my lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, password

I have tried using the security features using Device Manager on my Hudl 2 to Sony Xperia E1 running 4.4.2 KitKat. When I tried the lock feature, it made my phone ask for the password, but is there now anyway to stop that as it is a pain every time my screen locks? I have tried settings - security - screen lock but the none option is greyed out. I have also tried the "clear credentials" option, but no change.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lock screen options grayed out, that's usually enforced by some program that has been granted permission to act as a "device administrator". Most commonly, it's the stock Mail app if you are connecting to a corporate mail server, or some corporate security software you may have been asked to install if you're connecting to a company network.

Go to **Settings→Security→Device Administrators** and see if there are any applications listed with a check mark in the box on the right. If there are, you can try unchecking them one by one and going back to the Lock Screen settings each time to see which one is imposing the restriction.

**Be aware, however:** revoking an app's device administrator permission may result in loss of access to resources and/or the deletion of any data associated with that app. You *should* receive a warning/confirmation message if that is the case for a particular device administrator you're trying to deactivate. For example, if the Mail app became a device administrator as the result of configuring it to access a corporate Exchange account, you will lose access to the account and all data associated with that account will be deleted if you deactivate its device administrator status.

Comment: Exactly the direction I was thinking – specifically with David mentioning *I have tried using the security features using Device Manager*. Assuming he's speaking of Google's DM, that should be the most likely candidate (it requires being made device admin for remote lock, for example).

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.